# azure-pipelines - print variable to output

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am struggling with this simple task:

```
variables:
  myVariable: 'ValueFromVar'

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: ${myVariable} # prints empty

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Display version of app
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Write-Host "Version of app: ${myVariable}"' # prints empty

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: echo '${myVariable}' # prints ${myVariable}
```

What is the correct way how to print a variable to output within azure pipeline ??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

About how to use custom variables, please check the doc Set [variables in pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline).

In your case, when you want to use the variable, it should be `$(myVariable)` instead of `${myVariable}`.

Please refer to below demo:

```
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  myVariable: 'ValueFromVar'

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: '"$(myVariable)"'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Display version of app
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Write-Host "Version of app: $(myVariable)"' 

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: echo '$(myVariable)'
```

[image]

Comment: {facepalm}...In whole pipeline I use () and it didn't hit me.. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A clean one line approach is to use the [CmdLine task shortcut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml):

```
- script: echo $(myVariable)
```

Add display name etc. if needed e.g.

```
- script: echo $(myVariable)
  displayname: My variable value
```